# Numbers on arcs of a circle

Tags: combinatorics

> Consider a circle where $50$ people are, all of different ages. We can create a minimal pair out of two people X and Y.  X and Y are not sitting next to each other, and they form two arcs on the circle of the people between them. They satisfy the conditions for a minimal pair if in at least one of the arcs, everybody in the arc is older than both of them. What is the least number of minimal pairs possible?

I've tried solving this problem, and came to the conclusion that the answer should be 47, but I have no way to actually prove it. I used the chain of numbers: $1, 0, 2, 3, 4, ..., 49$. This created $47$ minimal pairs. I don't know how else I can prove this rigorously.

Comment: Can you explain how you got $47$ pairs out of that? Are arcs allowed to include portions of other arcs? (That seems likely). I can't imagine that a single rearrangement from the basic sequence is a likely answer. What else have you attempted?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: I have no proof but using some smaller $n$ and random configurations, the solution was $n-3$ no matter the order. You should be able to check $n=4,5$ completely to see it. I suspect proving it may be an induction placing a new (older) person in a random position at each step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim**: No matter the arrangement of the people at the table, for $n$ people ($n>3$) there will be $n-3$ arcs as defined above.

*Base Case*: $n=4$. We can see there are three possible orderings around the table: $1-2-3-4, 1-2-4-3, 1-3-2-4$. In each case there is $4-3=1$ arc, respectively $1-3, 2-3, 1-2$ for the three cases.

*Induction*: Consider a table with $k$ people seated and $k-3$ arcs. Person $k+1$ enters and sits between two random people who were previously seated next to one another. As both of those people have a number lower that $k+1$, a new arc is formed between the two people who are now separated by $k+1$.

Now consider a random arc already present before $k+1$ sits. That arc had two sides: on one side, all numbers are greater than the pair; on the other side, they are not. If $k+1$ sits on the side with all greater numbers, the arc does not change, as $k+1$ is greater than any of the numbers on that side. But if $k+1$ sits on the other side of the arc, it doesn't stop that side containing lower numbers, nor stop the first side having only higher numbers than the pair forming the arc.

Since this is true for any arc, it is true for every arc. Hence when person $k+1$ sits down, one new arc is created, giving $k-2=(k+1)-3$ arcs as desired. QED

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question though. In the case of the numbers from 1 to 50, like this: 1, 26, 2, 27, 3, 28, ... to 25, 50, 1, how would this turn out? I can count 49 arcs! I do not know if I am mistaken, please help.

Comment: In that sequence, there are 24 arcs in a sequence $1:2,2:3,3:4 \dots 24:25$. That's 24. Then there are 23 arcs in the sequence $1:3,1:4,1:5 \dots 1:25$. Where do you count two more? Or is it possible you counted $1:2$ and $1:25$ twice, as both really seem to belong in both sequences?

Comment: I see where I mis-counted. Thanks for ligma.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the different ages as $1,2,3,...,50.$

We use induction to calculate the answer. If we had $4$ people ($1,2,3,4$), the answer would be $1$.

We claim if we have $2n$ people, then the answer is $2n-3$, where $n\ge2$.

Assume we have $2n+2$ people, and name them as $1,2, ..., 2n+1, 2n+2$.

If the people of $1, 2, ..,, 2n$ are sitting around the circle, by induction, we have at least $2n-3$ arcs, and notice that the two people of $2n+1$ and $2n+2$ don't ruin any of the accepted arcs when they are added as well. Now, if $2n+1$ and $2n+2$ are added, in any way, to the circle, we, at least, get two new accepted arcs simply because $2n+1$ and $2n+2$ are greater than any of the other numbers.

For example, if $2k+1$ and $2k+2$ are adjacent, consider the other numbers next to those two and $2k+1$ and the other number next to $2k+2$ as new arcs. In case $2k+1$ and $2k+2$ are not adjacent, just consider the numbers next to either.

Hence, the claim is verified because $2n-3+2=2(n+1)-3$.

Comment: You say you add two arcs when $2n+1$ and $2n+2$ are seated, but you only increment the number of arcs by $1$ (to get $n$).

Comment: In fact, your ordering contains $47$ arcs: $(1-2, 2-3, \cdots 24-25)$ and $(1-3, 1-4, \cdots 1-25)$, for $24$ and $23$ respectively. In the second set of arcs, it's the long way around that contains all only larger numbers, e.g. between $1$ and $4$ are $47,5,46,\cdots 27,25,26$. The smaller numbers $2$ and $3$ are on the other side.

Comment: @EricSnyder YES. I had made a mistake about counting,, leading me to a wrong assumption. I edited my post. thank you

Comment: Also, technically, you need to prove the solution to the base case to make the induction complete. (That will be tough with $6$, which is why I started at $4$. There are... $60$ possible orderings with $6$ people I think? You'd need to show that the solution is $3$ for all of them.) --- It's actually really interesting to me that the minimum solution is, in fact, the maximum solution. You can't create *more* arcs either!

Comment: @EricSnyder Yes. Using $6$ is unnecessarily irrational, I think too. However the key point about this problem was using induction. The OP can easily polish the rest, I guess.

Comment: @EricSnyder Yes, it seems the maximum and minimum are the same. Indeed, the induction reveals how the number of arcs increases.